# How many ion channels on average must there be in one µm2 of neuronal membranes?

Tags: neuroscience, biophysics

If the conductance of a single ion channel is 1pS and its capacitance per cm2 is 1uF and the time constant for a human neuron is 1ms

How many ion channels on average must there be in one µm2 of neuronal membranes?

How is it possible to know how many ion channels with only these information? would you be able to explain it?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Suggest you check the given units and use those as a hint... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_(unit) and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farad comeback when you have made a slightly bigger effort.

Comment: Hi, so I have found the resistance which is = 1/ conductance = 1/1*10^-12 so resistance = 1*10^12 ohms per cm^2. (I converted the pS to S). However, I am confused what does it mean by "how many ion channels" do they actually want the number of ion channels, or is there a formula for that, i tried researching a lot but I did not find anything related. Thank you!

Comment: I know we have: Resistance, area (um^2), conductance and capacitance but i do not know how to put this information together to find the number of ion channels.

Comment: You also have a time constant. That will be key. Look for the relationship between the time constant and the other parameters you have. (note also: you have the conductance of just one channel; you are solving for how many channels you need i.e. how many multiples of that conductance)

Comment: does this mean we need to find current?

Comment: To notify a user, you should type @ before their name. For e.g. @BryanKrause

Comment: OP: I already gave you the hint that you need to use the time constant. Look up equations for the time constant that are in the units of the things you are studying: resistances, capacitances, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I expect your homework was already due, so...

You're supposed to remember what a membrane time constant is. I'll quote from page 12 of my (by now quite old) copy of "Ion channels of excitable membranes", by Hille:

> For biological membranes the product, R<sub>m</sub>C<sub>m</sub>, of membrane resistance and capacitance is often called the membrane time constant, tau<sub>m</sub>.

Since you know `tau` and `C`, your goal is then to determine the membrane resistance. You also need to convert the capacitance to square microns (1e<sup>-14</sup>F per square micron). In this case: 1ms/1e<sup>-14</sup>F = 1e<sup>11</sup>Ohms, or 1e<sup>-11</sup>S, or 10pS. So on average there are 10 channels per square micron, assuming I didn't make any silly mistakes.